# To output a warning tone when detecting objects using darknet

Tags: c, darknet

I am working on a task to detect objects using darknet.

Regardless of the object names, if the threshold exceeds a certain level, I would like to have a warning sound output.

I don't know where to put the alarm output code.

The code below is the image.c currently in use.

```
#ifndef _GNU_SOURCE
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#endif
#include "image.h"
#include "utils.h"
#include "blas.h"
#include "dark_cuda.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>
#ifndef _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#endif
#include <math.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "winmm.lib")
#define SOUND_NAME "alarm2.wav" 
#ifndef STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "stb_image.h"
#endif
#ifndef STB_IMAGE_WRITE_IMPLEMENTATION
#define STB_IMAGE_WRITE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "stb_image_write.h"
#endif

extern int check_mistakes;
//int windows = 0;

float colors[6][3] = { {1,0,1}, {0,0,1},{0,1,1},{0,1,0},{1,1,0},{1,0,0} };

float get_color(int c, int x, int max)
{
    float ratio = ((float)x/max)*5;
    int i = floor(ratio);
    int j = ceil(ratio);
    ratio -= i;
    float r = (1-ratio) * colors[i][c] + ratio*colors[j][c];
    //printf("%f\n", r);
    return r;
}

static float get_pixel(image m, int x, int y, int c)
{
    assert(x < m.w && y < m.h && c < m.c);
    return m.data[c*m.h*m.w + y*m.w + x];
}
static float get_pixel_extend(image m, int x, int y, int c)
{
    if (x < 0 || x >= m.w || y < 0 || y >= m.h) return 0;
    /*
    if(x < 0) x = 0;
    if(x >= m.w) x = m.w-1;
    if(y < 0) y = 0;
    if(y >= m.h) y = m.h-1;
    */
    if (c < 0 || c >= m.c) return 0;
    return get_pixel(m, x, y, c);
}
static void set_pixel(image m, int x, int y, int c, float val)
{
    if (x < 0 || y < 0 || c < 0 || x >= m.w || y >= m.h || c >= m.c) return;
    assert(x < m.w && y < m.h && c < m.c);
    m.data[c*m.h*m.w + y*m.w + x] = val;
}
static void add_pixel(image m, int x, int y, int c, float val)
{
    assert(x < m.w && y < m.h && c < m.c);
    m.data[c*m.h*m.w + y*m.w + x] += val;
}

void composite_image(image source, image dest, int dx, int dy)
{
    int x,y,k;
    for(k = 0; k < source.c; ++k){
        for(y = 0; y < source.h; ++y){
            for(x = 0; x < source.w; ++x){
                float val = get_pixel(source, x, y, k);
                float val2 = get_pixel_extend(dest, dx+x, dy+y, k);
                set_pixel(dest, dx+x, dy+y, k, val * val2);
            }
        }
    }
}

image border_image(image a, int border)
{
    image b = make_image(a.w + 2*border, a.h + 2*border, a.c);
    int x,y,k;
    for(k = 0; k < b.c; ++k){
        for(y = 0; y < b.h; ++y){
            for(x = 0; x < b.w; ++x){
                float val = get_pixel_extend(a, x - border, y - border, k);
                if(x - border < 0 || x - border >= a.w || y - border < 0 || y - border >= a.h) val = 1;
                set_pixel(b, x, y, k, val);
            }
        }
    }
    return b;
}

image tile_images(image a, image b, int dx)
{
    if(a.w == 0) return copy_image(b);
    image c = make_image(a.w + b.w + dx, (a.h > b.h) ? a.h : b.h, (a.c > b.c) ? a.c : b.c);
    fill_cpu(c.w*c.h*c.c, 1, c.data, 1);
    embed_image(a, c, 0, 0);
    composite_image(b, c, a.w + dx, 0);
    return c;
}

image get_label(image **characters, char *string, int size)
{
    if(size > 7) size = 7;
    image label = make_empty_image(0,0,0);
    while(*string){
        image l = characters[size][(int)*string];
        image n = tile_images(label, l, -size - 1 + (size+1)/2);
        free_image(label);
        label = n;
        ++string;
    }
    image b = border_image(label, label.h*.25);
    free_image(label);
    return b;
}

image get_label_v3(image **characters, char *string, int size)
{
    size = size / 10;
    if (size > 7) size = 7;
    image label = make_empty_image(0, 0, 0);
    while (*string) {
        image l = characters[size][(int)*string];
        image n = tile_images(label, l, -size - 1 + (size + 1) / 2);
        free_image(label);
        label = n;
        ++string;
    }
    image b = border_image(label, label.h*.05);
    free_image(label);
    return b;
}

void draw_label(image a, int r, int c, image label, const float *rgb)
{
    int w = label.w;
    int h = label.h;
    if (r - h >= 0) r = r - h;

    int i, j, k;
    for(j = 0; j < h && j + r < a.h; ++j){
        for(i = 0; i < w && i + c < a.w; ++i){
            for(k = 0; k < label.c; ++k){
                float val = get_pixel(label, i, j, k);
                set_pixel(a, i+c, j+r, k, rgb[k] * val);
            }
        }
    }
}

void draw_weighted_label(image a, int r, int c, image label, const float *rgb, const float alpha)
{
    int w = label.w;
    int h = label.h;
    if (r - h >= 0) r = r - h;

    int i, j, k;
    for (j = 0; j < h && j + r < a.h; ++j) {
        for (i = 0; i < w && i + c < a.w; ++i) {
            for (k = 0; k < label.c; ++k) {
                float val1 = get_pixel(label, i, j, k);
                float val2 = get_pixel(a, i + c, j + r, k);
                float val_dst = val1 * rgb[k] * alpha + val2 * (1 - alpha);
                set_pixel(a, i + c, j + r, k, val_dst);
            }
        }
    }
}

void draw_box_bw(image a, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, float brightness)
{
    //normalize_image(a);
    int i;
    if (x1 < 0) x1 = 0;
    if (x1 >= a.w) x1 = a.w - 1;
    if (x2 < 0) x2 = 0;
    if (x2 >= a.w) x2 = a.w - 1;

    if (y1 < 0) y1 = 0;
    if (y1 >= a.h) y1 = a.h - 1;
    if (y2 < 0) y2 = 0;
    if (y2 >= a.h) y2 = a.h - 1;

    for (i = x1; i <= x2; ++i) {
        a.data[i + y1*a.w + 0 * a.w*a.h] = brightness;
        a.data[i + y2*a.w + 0 * a.w*a.h] = brightness;
    }
    for (i = y1; i <= y2; ++i) {
        a.data[x1 + i*a.w + 0 * a.w*a.h] = brightness;
        a.data[x2 + i*a.w + 0 * a.w*a.h] = brightness;
    }
}

void draw_box_width_bw(image a, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int w, float brightness)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < w; ++i) {
        float alternate_color = (w % 2) ? (brightness) : (1.0 - brightness);
        draw_box_bw(a, x1 + i, y1 + i, x2 - i, y2 - i, alternate_color);
    }
}

void draw_box(image a, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, float r, float g, float b)
{
    //normalize_image(a);
    int i;
    if(x1 < 0) x1 = 0;
    if(x1 >= a.w) x1 = a.w-1;
    if(x2 < 0) x2 = 0;
    if(x2 >= a.w) x2 = a.w-1;

    if(y1 < 0) y1 = 0;
    if(y1 >= a.h) y1 = a.h-1;
    if(y2 < 0) y2 = 0;
    if(y2 >= a.h) y2 = a.h-1;

    for(i = x1; i <= x2; ++i){
        a.data[i + y1*a.w + 0*a.w*a.h] = r;
        a.data[i + y2*a.w + 0*a.w*a.h] = r;

        a.data[i + y1*a.w + 1*a.w*a.h] = g;
        a.data[i + y2*a.w + 1*a.w*a.h] = g;

        a.data[i + y1*a.w + 2*a.w*a.h] = b;
        a.data[i + y2*a.w + 2*a.w*a.h] = b;
    }
    for(i = y1; i <= y2; ++i){
        a.data[x1 + i*a.w + 0*a.w*a.h] = r;
        a.data[x2 + i*a.w + 0*a.w*a.h] = r;

        a.data[x1 + i*a.w + 1*a.w*a.h] = g;
        a.data[x2 + i*a.w + 1*a.w*a.h] = g;

        a.data[x1 + i*a.w + 2*a.w*a.h] = b;
        a.data[x2 + i*a.w + 2*a.w*a.h] = b;
    }
}

void draw_box_width(image a, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int w, float r, float g, float b)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < w; ++i){
        draw_box(a, x1+i, y1+i, x2-i, y2-i, r, g, b);
    }
}

void draw_bbox(image a, box bbox, int w, float r, float g, float b)
{
    int left  = (bbox.x-bbox.w/2)*a.w;
    int right = (bbox.x+bbox.w/2)*a.w;
    int top   = (bbox.y-bbox.h/2)*a.h;
    int bot   = (bbox.y+bbox.h/2)*a.h;

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < w; ++i){
        draw_box(a, left+i, top+i, right-i, bot-i, r, g, b);
    }
}

image **load_alphabet()
{
    int i, j;
    const int nsize = 8;
    image** alphabets = (image**)xcalloc(nsize, sizeof(image*));
    for(j = 0; j < nsize; ++j){
        alphabets[j] = (image*)xcalloc(128, sizeof(image));
        for(i = 32; i < 127; ++i){
            char buff[256];
            sprintf(buff, "data/labels/%d_%d.png", i, j);
            alphabets[j][i] = load_image_color(buff, 0, 0);
        }
    }
    return alphabets;
}



// Creates array of detections with prob > thresh and fills best_class for them
detection_with_class* get_actual_detections(detection *dets, int dets_num, float thresh, int* selected_detections_num, char **names)
{
    int selected_num = 0;
    detection_with_class* result_arr = (detection_with_class*)xcalloc(dets_num, sizeof(detection_with_class));
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < dets_num; ++i) {
        int best_class = -1;
        float best_class_prob = thresh;
        int j;
        for (j = 0; j < dets[i].classes; ++j) {
            int show = strncmp(names[j], "dont_show", 9);
            if (dets[i].prob[j] > best_class_prob && show) {
                best_class = j;
                best_class_prob = dets[i].prob[j];
            }
        }
        if (best_class >= 0) {
            result_arr[selected_num].det = dets[i];
            result_arr[selected_num].best_class = best_class;
            ++selected_num;
        }
    }
    if (selected_detections_num)
        *selected_detections_num = selected_num;
    return result_arr;
}

// compare to sort detection** by bbox.x
int compare_by_lefts(const void *a_ptr, const void *b_ptr) {
    const detection_with_class* a = (detection_with_class*)a_ptr;
    const detection_with_class* b = (detection_with_class*)b_ptr;
    const float delta = (a->det.bbox.x - a->det.bbox.w/2) - (b->det.bbox.x - b->det.bbox.w/2);
    return delta < 0 ? -1 : delta > 0 ? 1 : 0;
}

// compare to sort detection** by best_class probability
int compare_by_probs(const void *a_ptr, const void *b_ptr) {
    const detection_with_class* a = (detection_with_class*)a_ptr;
    const detection_with_class* b = (detection_with_class*)b_ptr;
    float delta = a->det.prob[a->best_class] - b->det.prob[b->best_class];
    return delta < 0 ? -1 : delta > 0 ? 1 : 0;
}

void draw_detections_v3(image im, detection *dets, int num, float thresh, char **names, image **alphabet, int classes, int ext_output)
{
    static int frame_id = 0;
    frame_id++;

    int selected_detections_num;
    detection_with_class* selected_detections = get_actual_detections(dets, num, thresh, &selected_detections_num, names);

    // text output
    qsort(selected_detections, selected_detections_num, sizeof(*selected_detections), compare_by_lefts);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < selected_detections_num; ++i) {
        const int best_class = selected_detections[i].best_class;
        printf("%s: %.0f%%", names[best_class],    selected_detections[i].det.prob[best_class] * 100);
        if (ext_output)
            printf("\t(left_x: %4.0f   top_y: %4.0f   width: %4.0f   height: %4.0f)\n",
                round((selected_detections[i].det.bbox.x - selected_detections[i].det.bbox.w / 2)*im.w),
                round((selected_detections[i].det.bbox.y - selected_detections[i].det.bbox.h / 2)*im.h),
                round(selected_detections[i].det.bbox.w*im.w), round(selected_detections[i].det.bbox.h*im.h));
        else
            printf("\n");
        int j;
        for (j = 0; j < classes; ++j) {
            if (selected_detections[i].det.prob[j] > thresh && j != best_class) {
                printf("%s: %.0f%%", names[j], selected_detections[i].det.prob[j] * 100);

                if (ext_output)
                    printf("\t(left_x: %4.0f   top_y: %4.0f   width: %4.0f   height: %4.0f)\n",
                        round((selected_detections[i].det.bbox.x - selected_detections[i].det.bbox.w / 2)*im.w),
                        round((selected_detections[i].det.bbox.y - selected_detections[i].det.bbox.h / 2)*im.h),
                        round(selected_detections[i].det.bbox.w*im.w), round(selected_detections[i].det.bbox.h*im.h));
                else
                    printf("\n");
            }
        }

    }

    // image output
    qsort(selected_detections, selected_detections_num, sizeof(*selected_detections), compare_by_probs);
    for (i = 0; i < selected_detections_num; ++i) {
            int width = im.h * .002;
            if (width < 1)
                width = 1;

            /*
            if(0){
            width = pow(prob, 1./2.)*10+1;
            alphabet = 0;
            }
            */

            //printf("%d %s: %.0f%%\n", i, names[selected_detections[i].best_class], prob*100);
            int offset = selected_detections[i].best_class * 123457 % classes;
            float red = get_color(2, offset, classes);
            float green = get_color(1, offset, classes);
            float blue = get_color(0, offset, classes);
            float rgb[3];

            //width = prob*20+2;

            rgb[0] = red;
            rgb[1] = green;
            rgb[2] = blue;
            box b = selected_detections[i].det.bbox;
            //printf("%f %f %f %f\n", b.x, b.y, b.w, b.h);

            int left = (b.x - b.w / 2.)*im.w;
            int right = (b.x + b.w / 2.)*im.w;
            int top = (b.y - b.h / 2.)*im.h;
            int bot = (b.y + b.h / 2.)*im.h;

            if (left < 0) left = 0;
            if (right > im.w - 1) right = im.w - 1;
            if (top < 0) top = 0;
            if (bot > im.h - 1) bot = im.h - 1;

            //int b_x_center = (left + right) / 2;
            //int b_y_center = (top + bot) / 2;
            //int b_width = right - left;
            //int b_height = bot - top;
            //sprintf(labelstr, "%d x %d - w: %d, h: %d", b_x_center, b_y_center, b_width, b_height);

            // you should create directory: result_img
            //static int copied_frame_id = -1;
            //static image copy_img;
            //if (copied_frame_id != frame_id) {
            //    copied_frame_id = frame_id;
            //    if (copy_img.data) free_image(copy_img);
            //    copy_img = copy_image(im);
            //}
            //image cropped_im = crop_image(copy_img, left, top, right - left, bot - top);
            //static int img_id = 0;
            //img_id++;
            //char image_name[1024];
            //int best_class_id = selected_detections[i].best_class;
            //sprintf(image_name, "result_img/img_%d_%d_%d_%s.jpg", frame_id, img_id, best_class_id, names[best_class_id]);
            //save_image(cropped_im, image_name);
            //free_image(cropped_im);

            if (im.c == 1) {
                draw_box_width_bw(im, left, top, right, bot, width, 0.8);    // 1 channel Black-White
            }
            else {
                draw_box_width(im, left, top, right, bot, width, red, green, blue); // 3 channels RGB
            }
            if (alphabet) {
                char labelstr[4096] = { 0 };
                strcat(labelstr, names[selected_detections[i].best_class]);
                char prob_str[10];
                sprintf(prob_str, ": %.2f", selected_detections[i].det.prob[selected_detections[i].best_class]);
                strcat(labelstr, prob_str);
                int j;
                for (j = 0; j < classes; ++j) {
                    if (selected_detections[i].det.prob[j] > thresh && j != selected_detections[i].best_class) {
                        strcat(labelstr, ", ");
                        strcat(labelstr, names[j]);
                    }
                }
                image label = get_label_v3(alphabet, labelstr, (im.h*.02));
                //draw_label(im, top + width, left, label, rgb);
                draw_weighted_label(im, top + width, left, label, rgb, 0.7);
                free_image(label);
            }
            if (selected_detections[i].det.mask) {
                image mask = float_to_image(14, 14, 1, selected_detections[i].det.mask);
                image resized_mask = resize_image(mask, b.w*im.w, b.h*im.h);
                image tmask = threshold_image(resized_mask, .5);
                embed_image(tmask, im, left, top);
                free_image(mask);
                free_image(resized_mask);
                free_image(tmask);
            }
    }
    free(selected_detections);
}

void draw_detections(image im, int num, float thresh, box *boxes, float **probs, char **names, image **alphabet, int classes)
{
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < num; ++i){
        int class_id = max_index(probs[i], classes);
        float prob = probs[i][class_id];
        if(prob > thresh){
            //// for comparison with OpenCV version of DNN Darknet Yolo v2
            //printf("\n %f, %f, %f, %f, ", boxes[i].x, boxes[i].y, boxes[i].w, boxes[i].h);
            // int k;
            //for (k = 0; k < classes; ++k) {
            //    printf("%f, ", probs[i][k]);
            //}
            //printf("\n");

            int width = im.h * .012;

            if(0){
                width = pow(prob, 1./2.)*10+1;
                alphabet = 0;
            }

            int offset = class_id*123457 % classes;
            float red = get_color(2,offset,classes);
            float green = get_color(1,offset,classes);
            float blue = get_color(0,offset,classes);
            float rgb[3];

            //width = prob*20+2;

            rgb[0] = red;
            rgb[1] = green;
            rgb[2] = blue;
            box b = boxes[i];

            int left  = (b.x-b.w/2.)*im.w;
            int right = (b.x+b.w/2.)*im.w;
            int top   = (b.y-b.h/2.)*im.h;
            int bot   = (b.y+b.h/2.)*im.h;

            if(left < 0) left = 0;
            if(right > im.w-1) right = im.w-1;
            if(top < 0) top = 0;
            if(bot > im.h-1) bot = im.h-1;
            printf("%s: %f%%", names[class_id], prob * 100);

            //printf(" - id: %d, x_center: %d, y_center: %d, width: %d, height: %d",
            //    class_id, (right + left) / 2, (bot - top) / 2, right - left, bot - top);

            printf("\n");
            draw_box_width(im, left, top, right, bot, width, red, green, blue);
            if (alphabet) {
                image label = get_label(alphabet, names[class_id], (im.h*.03)/10);
                draw_label(im, top + width, left, label, rgb);
               
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please dont spam language tags. The code is either C, C++ or pyhton, but not all three

Comment: I modified it. Is it correct?

Comment: no it is not correct. I know that the code is not python, so why did you tag it? I am not sure if this is valid C or valid C++, it could be both, but what matters is whether you compile it as C or compile it as C++, they are different languages

Comment: Sir, I modified it again. It's C. Is it right now? This file name is image.c
I left the tag on the recommendation list.

Answer (score 0):

It is a design issue, rather then a right/wrong answer.  I would suggest when in
`draw_detections_v3()` when `selected_detections_num > 0`:

```
int selected_detections_num = 0 ;
detection_with_class* selected_detections = get_actual_detections(dets, num, thresh, &selected_detections_num, names);

// Your alarm code here (example)
if( selected_detections_num )
{
    putchar( `\a` ) ;  // Audible alert to console - replace with 
                       // suitable audible alert if you need.
}
```

Comment: I wrote the code as follows.

void draw_detections_v3(image im, detection *dets, int num, float thresh, char **names, image **alphabet, int classes, int ext_output)
{
    static int frame_id = 0;
    frame_id++;

    int selected_detections_num = 0 ;
    detection_with_class* selected_detections = get_actual_detections(dets, num, thresh, &selected_detections_num, names);
    if (selected_detections_num)
    {
        PlaySound("alarm2.wav", 0, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC);
        _getch();
    }
But it does not work. I don’t' know the reason. :-(

Comment: @뭐요뭐요 Don't post code comments.  "does not work" is not a useful diagnostic.  Run it in your debugger and see if `selected_detections_num` is ever non-zero.  Perhaps `draw_detections_v3()` is never called - nothing in the code presented calls it.  Perhaps do it in `get_actual_detections()` instead, but the audible alert is a presentation rather than a detection issue which is why I suggested putting it in the same place as the draw.

Comment: Thank you. I'll change my mind when I ask additional questions.

Comment: I don't know if I understand correctly. The code that calls the alarm is in 
selected_detections_num. And the code should be in the same position as draw() because it is a presentation. But there is no code to call selected_detections_num. So selected_detections_num is not called.

Comment: @뭐요뭐요 It is your code, not mine - if you don't understand how it works, there is no helping you.  Do you currently have detection working? It is a simple matter if using the audible alert at the point of detection surely?  If it is not your code, run it in your debugger to see how it works and where the alert might be raised.

Comment: I think I have to touch the draw_detections_v3 to sound an alarm. If an object is detected, the selected_detections_num should be changed because the alarm should sound. selected_detections_num comes from get_actual_detections. I think get_actual_detections code shows the biggest box of values....... I need time to think. This problem is difficult because it hasn't been long since I started programming. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: I solved this problem. I don't know if this solution is accurate. I modified Image_opencv.cpp. I found a problematic value by finding *100 of all the files in the project and modifying them one by one. Noticing that this value represents a matching rate in the box, I added code to it. I sincerely thank you for helping me solve it myself.